# Smart Map - Static map displays fine, dynamic map does not

Tags: plugin-smartmap

I enabled the three API's at Google:

> Google Maps JavaScript API
>
> Google Maps Geocoding API
>
> Google Static Maps API

I get a static map OK. All I get with the dynamic map is a "Loading Map...".

My code:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('groups').limit(5).find() %}
    <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }} , {{ entry.address }}, {{ craft.smartMap.map(entry.address) }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors? Those can be illuminating.

Comment: Echoing what @MarionNewlevant said... Turn on the console, and see if any errors are being displayed there.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that some other JavaScript (unrelated to Smart Map) is throwing an error, and Smart Map never gets a chance to load the map. Loading a dynamic map is intentionally done late in the process, so that it doesn't interfere with other scripts you may have running.

The static map is simply loaded as a remote image, so no JavaScript is required.

Comment: Darn...just answered the wrong thread. There are indeed js errors:

Comment: /cpresources/smartmap/css/smartmap.css?x=MAzgVq0Oy Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
smartmap.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
smartmap.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
xx.xx.xx.xx/:73 Uncaught ReferenceError: smartMap is not defined
    at xx.xx.xx.xx/:73
content.js:10 
smartmap.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Is the public `/cpresources` folder writable? Craft needs to copy files there from the backend when the page initially loads.

Comment: Using find I cannot find a folder or file named "/cpresources". Where should it be?

Comment: It should be in your `/web` folder. (Or if you've renamed it, then whatever that folder is currently named.)

Comment: /craft/app/etc/web or /craft/app/framework/web? Those are the only two web folders I have. Neither contain a folder named /cpresources. Changing both to 777 did not fix the issue.